# Python threading: access a shared variable that is being locked at the moment

Tags: python, multithreading

Here is a situation that seems to cause problem to my program. There two threads, one thread has locks shared variables, while the other, wants to access one shared variable. So what will happen in this case, does the second thread just wait till the lock is released? or there will be errors since thread 2 is accessing locked variables?

Comment: I'd guess that 'reading' a locked variable is ok. However, you can check with the 'locked()' function to see if it is locked, while loop the check, and when no longer true do your code and take the lock on the second thread.

Comment: thank you. yes i used locked() to check the status and it seems a way to avoid the issue.

Comment: It depends on the variable and whether the compare takes multiple steps. If its a string for example, then `shared_var == 'some value'` would be fine. How long does the other thread hold the lock? You could grab it yourself. But if its a single value, you likely don't have to.

Comment: It's actually a big object of a machine learning model class, it has a model training step and so the lock is held pretty long.